# MAM and Android: fingerprint option never shown

Tags: fingerprint, android-enterprise, microsoft-intune

We're trying to configure Intune so that people with Android devices can access their corporate email through Outlook for Android. In the Access Requirements blade (dashboard > client apps- app protection policies > intune app protection - properties), we've activated PIN (including simple PINs) and fingerprint for accessing the apps.

Whenever a user tries to access the corporate email through Outlook, it's prompted to install the Intune app (company portal app) from the store. After doing that, the user is asked for a PIN after setting up the corporate email account in Outlook. After the specified timeout, the user will be asked for a PIN again. However, the app never allows the users to use fingerprints to unlock the app. It will only allow the user to enter the PIN.

The Intune portal seems to imply that I should be able to use a fingerprint (instead of a PIN) to access the mail, but we've tried it on a couple of Android Devices (OnePlus 3T and 5T) and the fingerprint option is never shown.

Any ideas on what's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd36899e-5bb3-41f6-9754-7d1833dfa4ec/fingerprint-instead-of-pin?forum=microsoftintuneprod?

Comment: Hello Robert. Yes I've tried following the docs for setting intine, but I'm surely missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for it to work, you need to create a work profile and associate the fingerprint to that profile.